# ASP.NET Core 7 : edit requests to controller with large request returns 400 error

Tags: asp.net-core-7.0, 400-bad-request

I'm using ASP.NET Core 7. I have an update form which results in an http 400 error for large dataset updates. It works fine when the data being updated is smaller. The error I get is

> This page isn't working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 400

The update method on the controller is set to HTTP `POST`.

For large data set edits, the POST method is not hit at all. If I run a Chrome debug console, I see the failed to load resource error which points to `chrome-error://chromewebdata/`. I have tried installing Postman Interceptor and capturing the request. It captures it successfully and does not show any issues. I am able to browse the data.

The data seems to be sent as `x-www-form-ulrencoded`. Is this my issue? Is there a limit to `POST` data size? Is there a way to increase this limit?

My controller code looks like this

```cs
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
{
    // . . . 

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ReticleSetEntity entity)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // . . . 
        }
        // ....
    }
}
```

The HTML looks like this

```html
<form id="reticleset-form" asp-action="Edit" >
<div class="card mt-4">
. . .
```

Many thanks for any help

Comment: What is your request consist of (just form data? maybe files?) and what is the size of your payload?

Answer (score 1):

The specifics about the request contents and size could help. Also, limits could be added by your hosting environment (e.g. IIS).

But here you can find few options to change the limits: https://www.textcontrol.com/blog/2019/12/20/documentviewer-configuring-aspnet-for-larger-requests/.

### Updated

Form value count limit could be configured via [`FormOptions.ValueCountLimit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.formoptions.valuecountlimit?view=aspnetcore-8.0). You can do it while configuring services:

```
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => options.ValueCountLimit = 5000);
```

Comment: The request consists of an object that has a sub collection of objects.  I notice the error happening for an object with 98 sub objects.  These objects are pocos. 10-20 properties ranging from strings to its to longs etc.
@Alexander Burov The link you sent me seems to be for older asp.net framework.  I am using .net 7.  I don't have web.config, I have appsettings.json.

Comment: I removed the [Authorize] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attributes from my post method.  This allowed the post method to be hit.  I can now see a validation error which reads as follows "Failed to read the request form. Form value count limit 1024 exceeded."  Is there a way to increase this limit?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this puppy out. Firstly I removed the  [Authorize] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attributes from my post method. This allowed a form submit to actually hit the post method.  It was returning a null payload but I was able to see a validation error message thus - "Failed to read the request form. Form value count limit 1024 exceeded."  Once I had this, I was able to find a great article showing how to increase this limit. The solution involves creating a new "RequestFormSizeLimitAttribute" attribute and decorating the post method with it as per option 2.
[https://www.kellton.com/kellton-tech-blog/how-submit-large-number-form-values-aspnet-core#:~:text=If%20you%20wish%20to%20submit,and%20key%20length%20above%201024](https://www.kellton.com/kellton-tech-blog/how-submit-large-number-form-values-aspnet-core#:%7E:text=If%20you%20wish%20to%20submit,and%20key%20length%20above%201024).

```
public class RequestFormSizeLimitAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    private readonly FormOptions _formOptions;

    public int Order { get; set; }


    public RequestFormSizeLimitAttribute(int valueCountLimit)
    {
        _formOptions = new FormOptions() { ValueCountLimit = valueCountLimit };
    }


    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var features = context.HttpContext.Features;
        var formFeature = features.Get<IFormFeature>();
        if (formFeature == null || formFeature.Form == null)
        {
            features.Set<IFormFeature>(new FormFeature(context.HttpContext.Request, _formOptions));
        }
    }
```

Use in the controller thus

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[RequestFormSizeLimit(valueCountLimit: 20000, Order = 1)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Order = 2)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ReticleSetEntity entity)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
     . . .
```